# how send multiple push notification send in android

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

when i trying to send multiple push notification that a time i m getting error like .

my PHP coding is :-

```
<?php

//Sending Push Notification
function send_push_notification($device_id, $msg)
{
//echo "fdff";
    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

     //$message1 = array("header" => $msg);
    $x = array($device_id);

     $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $x,
        'data' => array("message" => $msg),
    );
    //print_r($fields);
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . "AIzaSyAYmZljXmJWgIqD5sQ9_0d-    jUVorm3ZnhA",
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
?>
```

and this is my error.

```
{"multicast_id":5911003352460212858,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}

{"multicast_id":5737426372728217758,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":1,"results":[{"registration_id":"APA91bHa4mmnj2EZfiN7EVa5c_eCVKBkQJmImpfedThbwoxyzlxh3f_NGRJ8mVCp63JQnL8ZvKvtH6P_Nz5O_MKu1Kgy7d2oJhLt6-82xK499n1P_mTp6t4m11ERlaU6Oe6vEmqG6CBu","message_id":"0:1449254314294720%66e3e4c4f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

in this code i have success in two devices but in one device is not send.
so how this possible?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by sending multiple push notifications? Are you sending multiple notifications to a single device, or one notification to many devices?

Comment: I couldn't understand your question, please edit your question an describe more about it.

Comment: @ArthurThompson one notification to send multiple devices.

Comment: @Ali When i trying to send one notification to multiple devices that a time i getting to this type of error. one device send successfully but other device its gone in failure.

Comment: Please put your JSON request in your question, to check if there is a problem or not.

Comment: @Ali i have edit my question for php side function .

Comment: I think you'd better to setup a device group or subscribed group and then push the message to the `message_id` to all the device in that group. For more details, please refer to here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications